GCP worflows with cloud function and bigquery
I'm trying to query the table and paste that in gcs bucket and from there gcs to sftp location. To transfer to sftp I'm calling cloud functions. Using gcp workflows as the for this process and getting the input to this workflow is by json file
When I am trying to write the yaml file it is throwing an error every time when I use the for loop. If I don't use the for loop it is easily creating the workflows. Unable to use the for loop for workflows. Below is the code.
main:
  params:
    [input]
  steps:
    - initialize_workflow:
        assign:
          - arguments: ${input.arguments}
          - output: {}
    - iterate_arguments:
        foreach:
          value: argument
          in: ${arguments}
          steps:
            - initialize_single_argument:
                assign:
                  - cloud_function_url: ${argument.cloud_function_url}
                  - dbt_service_url: ${argument.dbt_service_url + "/dbt"}
                  - project_id: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
                  - query: ${argument.export_query}
                  - upload_bucket: ${argument.upload_bucket}
                  - history_bucket: ${argument.history_bucket}
                  - dbt_selector: ${argument.dbt_selector}
                  - dbt_macro: ${argument.dbt_macro}
                  - dbt_args: ${argument.dbt_args}
                  - filename: ${argument.file_name}
                  - exported_filename: ${argument.exported_file_name}
                  - current_timestamp: ${text.substring(time.format(sys.now()), 0, 19)}
            - create_full_export_filename:
                assign:
                  - full_exported_filename:
                      ${exported_filename + "_" + current_timestamp + ".csv"}
            - execute_dbt_run_selector:
                call: http.post
                args:
                  url: ${dbt_service_url}
                  auth:
                    type: OIDC
                    timeout: 1800
                  body:
                    verb:
                      run
                    selector:
                      ${dbt_selector}
                result: dbt_run_selector_response
            - set_dbt_run_selector_output:
                assign:
                  - output["run"]: ${dbt_run_selector_response.body}
            - execute_dbt_test_selector:
                call:
                  http.post
                args:
                  url:
                    ${dbt_service_url}
                  auth:
                    type: OIDC
                    timeout: 1800
                  body:
                    verb:
                      test
                    selector:
                      ${dbt_selector}
                  result:
                    dbt_test_selector_response
            - set_dbt_test_selector_output:
                assign:
                  - output["test"]: ${dbt_test_selector_response.body}
            - bigquery_table_to_gcs:
                call:
                  googleapis.bigquery.v2.jobs.query
                args:
                  projectId:
                    ${project_id}
                  body:
                    query:
                      ${"EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(uri='gs://" + upload_bucket + "/" + filename + "_*.csv', format='CSV', overwrite=true, header=true, field_delimiter = ',') AS " + query}
                    useLegacySql:
                      false
            - execute_cloud_function:
                call:
                  http.get
                args:
                  url:
                    ${cloud_function_url}
                  auth:
                    type: OIDC
                    audience:
                      ${cloud_function_url}
                result:
                  execute_cloud_function_result
            - status_polling:
                switch:
                  - condition:
                      ${execute_cloud_function_result.body == "OK"}
                    next: copy
                next: error_case
            - error_case:
                return:
                  ${execute_cloud_function_result}
            - copy:
                call:
                  googleapis.storage.v1.objects.copy
                args:
                  destinationBucket: ${history_bucket}
                  destinationObject: ${full_exported_filename}
                  sourceBucket: ${upload_bucket}
                  sourceObject: ${exported_filename + ".csv"}
            - update_functions:
                call:
                  http.post
                args:
                  url:
                    ${dbt_service_url}
                  auth:
                    type: OIDC
                    timeout: 1800
                  body:
                    verb: run-operation
                    macro: ${dbt_macro}
                    args: ${dbt_args}
                result:
                  dbt_run_selector_response
            - set_dbt_run_macro_output:
                assign:
                  - output["run"]:
                      ${dbt_run_selector_response.body}
    - finalize_workflow:
        return: ${output}



{
  "argument": [
    {
      "cloud_function_url": "url",
      "dbt_service_url": "url",
      "export_query": "select * from project_1.dataset_1.table_1 LIMIT 1000000000",
      "upload_bucket": "bucket_1",
      "history_bucket": "bucket_hist_1",
      "file_name": "p_file",
      "exported_file_name": "p_file_000000000000",
      "dbt_selector": "daily_schedule",
      "dbt_macro": "update_table",
      "dbt_args": {
        "target_table": "project_1.dataset_1.table_1",
        "source_table": "project_1.dataset_1.view_1"
      }
    },
    {
      "cloud_function_url": "url",
      "dbt_service_url": "url",
      "export_query": "select * from project_2.dataset_2.table_2 LIMIT 1000000000",
      "upload_bucket": "bucket_2",
      "history_bucket": "bucket_hist_2",
      "file_name": "p_file_1",
      "exported_file_name": "p_file_1_000000000000",
      "dbt_selector": "daily_schedule",
      "dbt_macro": "update_table",
      "dbt_args": {
        "target_table": "project_2.dataset_2.table_2",
        "source_table": "project_2.dataset_2.table_2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "callLogLevel": "LOG_ALL_CALLS"
}


The keyword is 'for', not 'foreach'.
